# Open portfolio image in light box

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am creating a website using [chamber theme](http://www.gallyapp.com/tf_themes/?theme=Chamber).

This is the portfolio of my site like this. Now I want to open these portfolio images in lightbox, but I didn't find where to be change in the code.

My `portfolio.php` is

```
session_start();

if (!isset($hide_header) OR !$hide_header) {
    get_header();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['pp_portfolio_style'])) {
    $pp_portfolio_style = $_SESSION['pp_portfolio_style'];
}
else {
    $pp_portfolio_style = get_option('pp_portfolio_style');
}

if (empty($pp_portfolio_style)) {
    $pp_portfolio_style = '2';
}

include(TEMPLATEPATH."/templates/template-portfolio-".$pp_portfolio_style.".php");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a great plugin for this. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/ "fancy box for wordpress" I have tried a few and lots of the time they dont work the way I want or dont work at all. This one has not failed me yet. It automatically turns galleries and images (if you link them to the FILENAME.jpg) to open in a light box effect.

Comment: no,its not working in this chamber theme...please suggest another plugin or implemention in the code.